# Feature request: display LaTeX on mouseover.

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

I think it would be great to see the LaTeX source for any equations that are displayed without having to right-click --> show math as... etc. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this would be annoying. I hate it when you are minding your own business, trying to do some maths, and your mouse accidentally veers into the space occupied by an advert and suddenly your whole screen is advising you to buy "Denham's Dentifrice". It isn't that much effort to read the source, and I wouldn't be interested in it usually. Perhaps this would be more useful as a browser plugin (which would work on all sites using MathJax, not just here)?

Comment: Related, and nearly duplicated: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/context-menu-should-allow-easy-copying-of-tex-commands

Comment: Well it already happens when one hovers over tags and question titles - not too bothersome. I think it would help in writing answers just to have a quick way of referring to the conventions, symbols etc that are being used in the question.

Comment: @Epictetus: Ah, sorry, I was envisaging it being immediate, not hovering.